# Sql query a field with a hash tag split character

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I want to query a field in my Database, which corresponds with a listview in my software. Multiple selection is of course possible. For this example, the options in the listview are as follows: "opt1", "opt2", "opt3", "opt4". The records are saved in the database as follows:

For 1 listview option: "Opt1"
For multiple options: "Opt1#Opt3"   -- or "Opt3#Opt4"   -- or "Opt1#Opt4#Opt3"  --etc. You get the drift.

- how can I query this, if I want to count all occurances of a certain option?
- how can I query this if I want to count occurances of 1 particular option?

If we would call the parameter, say,  @ListViewSelection  ?

Select count...? I'm stuck, because of the # split character

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ouch.  Welcome to the wonderful (terrible) world of multi-value columns.  Benefits include: Not being able to use indices properly, Requiring tricky or otherwise complicated queries, and Terrible times updating the column and any dependencies.  Please 'reward' the original designer by 'spindle, fold, and mutilate', then normalize this (you'll need an `Option` table).

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from tablename where listview like '%Opt1%'
```

Be sure to pass the pattern as a bound parameter to avoid injection attacks,

```
select count(*) from tablename where listview like ?
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but it seems that it is not that simple.. Say that I want to count occurances of both Opt1 as as Opt2? And that there are an indefinite amount of options possible (theoretically)

Comment: @wouter - Unless the backing RDBMS allows things like Regex, there's only two ways to do this: 1) Construct a (temporary) table/CTE with the tags as individual rows, and 'count' as if it were another table (some have different features that may also fall into this category). 2) Use a `LIKE` clause for _each_ option to be searched for, using `AND` or `OR` as necessary.

Comment: thanks, 1st option is the way to go I guess.. I was hoping there'd be an easier way though ;-)